# Android SDK 14 - Can't Create GTV device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, qemu, google-tv

I'm a Google TV developer, and today, shortly after the android sdk 14 was released, I updated everything, from the android sdk to the eclipse ADT. Since then, I can't create a Google TV virtual device. I came to the point where I completely deleted everything and tried to do a fresh install. Here is what happens:

With a fresh download of the android sdk with only Android 3.1 and the Google TV add-on:

```
$ android list targets

Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-12"
     Name: Android 3.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 12
     Revision: 3
     Skins: WXGA (default)
     ABIs : armeabi
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google TV Addon:12"
     Name: Google TV Addon
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 2
     Based on Android 3.1 (API level 12)
     Skins: WXGA, 1080p-overscan, 1080p, 720p (default), 720p-overscan
     ABIs : x86

$ android create avd -n GTV -t 2
Auto-selecting single ABI x86
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ABI Type x86 is unknown for target Standard Android platform 3.1
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getImageRelativePath(AvdManager.java:885)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.setImagePathProperties(AvdManager.java:1637)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.createAvd(AvdManager.java:571)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.createAvd(Main.java:1110)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:253)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Can someone give me a hint on what am I doing wrong?? Or is it a Google problem?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem and have filed an issue for it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20963

Comment: thanks! perhaps google will release a fix now... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might try this workaround:

inside of ~/.android/avd/your_avd_name.avd/ create a file 'config.ini'

config.ini should look like:

```
hw.lcd.density=213
hw.keyboard.charmap=Emulator
skin.name=720.p
skin.path=add-ons/addon-google_tv-google_inc_-12/skins/720p
hw.cpu.arch=x86
abi.type=x86
vm.heapSize=256
hw.ramSize=1024
disk.dataPartition.size=128
image.sysdir.2=platforms/android-12/images/
image.sysdir.1=add-ons/addon-google_tv-google_inc_-12/images/x86/
```

**Update**

By default, the android tool creates the AVD directory inside ~/.android/avd/ (on Linux/Mac), C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and C:\Users\.android\ on Windows 7 and Vista. If you want to use a custom location for the AVD directory, you can do so by using the -p  option when you create the AVD:
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html

Comment: Confirmed, this config.ini fixed GoogleTV for me on AMD64 with KVM.

Thanks for sharing this powerj1984.

Comment: r15 of the plugin is available now and should fix this, I haven't been able to test it out yet though.