#  ABI Type armeabi is unknown for target null in Android Google TV avd

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, google-tv

When I update the `GoogeTV Av`d using android commands I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ABI Type armeabi is unknown for target null
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getImageRelativePath(AvdManager.java:885)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.setImagePathProperties(AvdManager.java:1627)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.updateAvd(AvdManager.java:1566)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.updateAvd(AvdManager.java:1543)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.updateAvd(Main.java:1251)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:270)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

where the `config.ini` file for this `avd` is :

```
hw.lcd.density=240
skin.name=WVGA800
skin.path=platforms/android-2.3.3_r01-linux/skins/WVGA800
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi
vm.heapSize=24
hw.ramSize=256
image.sysdir.2=platforms/android-2.3.3_r01-linux/images/
image.sysdir.1=add-ons/addon_google_apis_google_inc_10/images/
```

I have created this file manually as Android tools `R14` doesn't create it(a bug from Google I think) .. so what is the problem that cause this exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config.ini` file is invalid for Google TV -- wrong CPU, wrong skin, etc. Use the one outlined in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824203/android-sdk-14-cant-create-gtv-device/7843608#7843608).

Comment: I used this 'config.ini' but I got this response .